# MYSQL 5.7 and PopSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, popsql

Hi all programmer I hope all r u fine. Actually, I'm trying to learn MYSQL with popSQL (SQL editor) everything is fine when I use the MYSQL Client Command line but I want to write my query with popSQL but when try to connect with my database but it's given me an error like "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"
[image]

Comment: Check in .ini does MySQL is set for to use socket connection. Or set popSQL for to use IP connection.

Comment: Thank u for your sincerity but please could u tell me please in details so that I can solve my problem.........  I wanna get ride of it,......

Comment: I do not use popSQL. So I don't know how it must be set up.

Comment: Are you sure that your mysql server is actually running? Check the docs on mysqld to verify the correct procedure for your installation

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need select the Connection Type with "Connect directly from my computer"
just make a try

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30364527)